# How to loop through multiple values in the same string?

Tags: r

I wanna loop through a sequence of letters 'ABCDEFGHIJK', but the loop in R loops over 1 value at a time. Is there a way to loop over 3 values at a time? In this case the sequence 'ABCDEFGHIJK' would be looped as 'ABC' then 'DEF' and so on.

I've tried to change the length of the function but I still didn't find a way, I can do this in python but I didn't find any information about it in R nor in the help option of R.

```
xp <-'ACTGCT'
for(i in 1:length(xp)){
  if(i == 'ACG'){
    print('T')
  }
}
```

Comment: You are looping through a vector of length 1 and comparing the sequence with string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Base R** Iterate over the sequence 1, 4, 7, ... and use `substr` to extract the 3 character portion of the input string starting at that position number.  Then perform whatever processing that is desired. If there are fewer than 3 characters in the last chunk it will use whatever is available for that chunk.  This is a particularly good approach if you want to exit early since a `break` can be inserted into the loop.

```
for(i in seq(1, nchar(xp), 3)) {
  s <- substr(xp, i, i+2)
  print(s) # replace with desired processing
}
## [1] "ACT"
## [1] "GCT"
```

**1a) lapply**  We translate the loop to `lapply` or `sapply` if one iteration does not depend on another.

```
process <- function(i) { 
  s <- substr(xp, i, i+2)
  s  # replace with desired processing
}
sapply(seq(1, nchar(xp), 3), process)
## [1] "ACT" "GCT"
```

**2) rollapply** Another possibility is to break the string up into single characters and then iterate over those passing a 3 element vector of single characters to the indicated function. Here we have used `toString` to process each chunk but that can be replaced with any other suitable function.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(strsplit(xp, "")[[1]], 3, by = 3, toString, align = "left", partial = TRUE)
## [1] "A, C, T" "G, C, T"
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to split the string over each 3 characters and then do the comparison

```
lapply(strsplit(v1, "(?<=.{3})", perl = TRUE), function(x) x== 'ACG')
#[[1]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 'ABCDEFGHIJK'
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the vectorized `substring`, i.e.

```
substring('ABCDEFGHIJK', seq(1, nchar('ABCDEFGHIJK') - 1, 3), seq(3, nchar('ABCDEFGHIJK'), 3)) == 'ACG'
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**NOTE:** This will only extract 3-characters. So If at the end you are left with 2 characters, it will not return them. For the above example, it outputs:

```
substring('ABCDEFGHIJK', seq(1, nchar('ABCDEFGHIJK') - 1, 3), seq(3, nchar('ABCDEFGHIJK'), 3))
#[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `stringr` solution that outputs a list for whether or not there are matches:

```
library(stringr)

# Split string into sequences of 3 (or fewer if length is not multiple of 3)
split_strings <- str_extract_all("ABCDEFGHIJK", ".{1,3}", simplify = T)[1,]

# The strings you want to loop through / search for
x <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "LMN")

# Output is named list
sapply(x, `%in%`, split_strings, simplify = F)

$ABC
[1] TRUE

$DEF
[1] TRUE

$GHI
[1] TRUE

$LMN
[1] FALSE
```

Or, if you only want to look for one element:

```
"ABC" %in% split_strings
[1] TRUE
```